# search box scoped to a managed property

Tags: 2013, search, search-scope, result-source

I have created a managed property called *speakers* and it is working well when I use the following format speaker:nameofspeaker on the search box.

However I intend to use a search web part automatically scoped to this managed property, thus avoiding having to instruct users to type the above format.

users would only type *nameofspeaker* on the search box to get results. how do I achieve this?

Comment: I dont think this is possible with OOTB. you may need to develop custom search via api some thing link full text query search or extend the OOTB webparts by referring them in a custom control.

Comment: Use the results page not the search box. Just force the search box to your results page like Sekhar says below.

Answer (score 3):

Goto the search page where you are showing the results

Edit the Search results webpart

Edit the Query

change query to

speaker:{searchboxquery}